# same thread name for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: spring, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

Below is my config for Executor

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncServiceExecutorConfig extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {
    
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        executor.setCorePoolSize(xxx.getCorePoolSize());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(xxx.getMaxPoolSize());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(xxx.getQueueCapacity());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyAsync-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

That is how I call it.

```
    Executor executor = asyncExecutorConfig.getAsyncExecutor();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        
    }, executor);
```

When I print out the thread name, they all end with MyAsync-1

I set Thread.sleep in one MyAsync-1. The next new thread still shows as MyAsync-1

Did I do something wrong? Why it doesn't give me MyAsync-2, MyAsync-2, etc

---

**Updated:**

I tried to print out more details about threads. 10 threads are being created. They all have same thread name MyAsync-1

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class MyAsyncServiceExecutorConfig extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        executor.setCorePoolSize(0);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(2);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyAsync-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    Executor executor = myAsyncServiceExecutorConfig.getAsyncExecutor();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {

            log.info("Thread.currentThread().getName() = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, executor);
}

Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
threadSet.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getName().startsWith("MyAsync-"))
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getName() + " id = " + e.getId()));
```

Below is the result:

```
...
2023-02-08 14:04:31.107  INFO 7832 --- [      MyAsync-1] c.h.w.controller.MyController   : Thread.currentThread().getName() = MyAsync-1
2023-02-08 14:04:31.107  INFO 7832 --- [      MyAsync-1] c.h.w.controller.MyController   : Thread.currentThread().getName() = MyAsync-1
2023-02-08 14:04:31.107  INFO 7832 --- [      MyAsync-1] c.h.w.controller.MyController   : Thread.currentThread().getName() = MyAsync-1
MyAsync-1 id = 76
MyAsync-1 id = 70
MyAsync-1 id = 69
MyAsync-1 id = 73
MyAsync-1 id = 71
MyAsync-1 id = 77
MyAsync-1 id = 78
MyAsync-1 id = 74
MyAsync-1 id = 72
MyAsync-1 id = 75
```

Comment: It is a thread pool so will reuse the threads. What are your core and max poolsizes? What is your queue size?

Comment: Updated description with more testing. Threads are being created. But the thread name is not changed.

Comment: The problem is your core size is 0, max is 3, however the pool will only grow (new thread created) if the queue is swamped. If you enable more threads to begin with you will have multiple threads.

Comment: I still have same result:  MyAsync-1 with different  id = 79, id = 68  Are they not different threads?